# UiWatcher example for Android UIAutomator not working

Tags: android-uiautomator

> import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject;
>       import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
>       import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiSelector;
>       import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiWatcher;
>       import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;
>
> ```
> public class uiWatcherDemo extends UiAutomatorTestCase {
>
>   private static final String NOINTERNET_STRING = "InternetWatcher";
>
>   public void testWatcherDemoTestExample() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
>
>       // Define watcher and register //
>       UiWatcher internetWatcher = new UiWatcher() {
>           @Override
>           public boolean checkForCondition() {
>               UiObject noConnObj = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("No connection"));
>               if(noConnObj.exists()) {
>                   UiObject retryButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.Button").text("Retry"));
>                   try {
>                       retryButton.click();
>                       try { Thread.sleep(3000L); } catch(Exception e) {}
>                       getUiDevice().pressHome();
>                   } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
>                       e.printStackTrace();
>                   }
>               }
>               return false;
>           }
>       };
>       getUiDevice().registerWatcher(NOINTERNET_STRING, internetWatcher);
>       getUiDevice().runWatchers();
>
>       // app test code //
>       getUiDevice().pressHome();
>       UiObject allAppsButton = new UiObject(new   UiSelector().description("Apps"));
>       allAppsButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
>       UiObject appsTab = new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("Shop"));
>       appsTab.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
>
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok now I understand how UiWatcher works ...
Note : UiWatcher will invoke only when some API will be in retry mode . that means when some API call is not able to find an element from UI .. then UI library will automatically invoke your registered watcher.

So as per above example, open Google Play when internet connection is OFF .. now I want watcher to alive and check for the above condition and click to retry and go back to home page. Just add these two line at the end of the code .. which will be in retry mode then u can see registered watcher start working.

```
// below line will be in retry mode and Watcher will be invoke automatically //
        UiObject contact = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Contacts"));
        contact.click();
```